# Unable to listen on a specific port in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, server

I need to run "1017" port in my laptop as "localhost"  `http://127.0.0.1:1017`. To do that I run some file in /home directory. But after execute file I got following error message. How can I run above port as my "localhost".

```
listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:1017: bind: permission denied
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only listen on ports below 1024 using `sudo`. These are privileged ports:

> The TCP/IP port numbers below 1024 are special in that normal users are not allowed to run servers on them. This is a security feaure, in that if you connect to a service on one of these ports you can be fairly sure that you have the real thing, and not a fake which some hacker has put up for you.

[Source](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html)

---

Example:

```
$ nc -l 127.0.0.1 1017
nc: Permission denied
```

However this will work:

```
$ sudo nc -l 127.0.0.1 1017
```